# Get index of logstash split filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-filter

I am using Logstash split filter plugin as described in this page : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html

Let say I have data looking like that :

```
{"log_id": "abcd", "logs": [{"val": 3}, {"val": 4}]}
```

Using the split filter like this :

```
filter { split { field => "logs" } }
```

Would output documents as follow :

```
{"log_id": "abcd", "logs": {"val": 3}}
{"log_id": "abcd", "logs": {"val": 4}}
```

I would like to extract the index of the splited document to use as unique id as follow :

```
{"log_id": "abcd", "logs": {"val": 3}, "unique_id": "abcd-0"}
{"log_id": "abcd", "logs": {"val": 4}, "unique_id": "abcd-1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the patch I applied to fix this :

```
88c88
<     splits.each do |value|
---
>     splits.each_with_index do |value, index|
97a98
>       event_split.set("_split_idx", index)
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-split/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/split.rb), the plugin does not support this feature.  Please consider adding an issue there.